# How to approximate the division by a number like prime number?

Tags: approximation

I was solving some mathematical questions and have come across the situation, where I need to divide 3900/139. Here is my question,

a. Can I assume 139 to 140 for the ease of division?

If so, how will I know what percentage of error I am introducing? How can I ensure that I am adding very less value to a number and the results will not be tremendously affected?

Answer (score 1):

N/139 = real answer

N/140 = your answer

your answer/real answer = (N/140)/(N/139) = 139/140.

Your answer will be 1/140 too small.

====

in general if you replace p with (p + n) your result will by factor of n/(p+n)

Replace 487 with 500 and your be off by a factor of 13/500.

Basically your answer will be off be the same proportion as your rounding was off.

Comment: so, I can say 1/140 is kind of negligible and I don't have any deviation actually. But, this deviation matters if the multiplying factor is let's say 100000 to this fraction.

Comment: total deviation will be larger but in proportional the same. 100,000/99 = 1010.1.  But 100,000/100 = 1000 so you are off by 10.  Which is 1%. But 2/99 = .020202020.... But 2/100 = .02 so you are off by .0002.  Which is also 1%.

Comment: So x/140 rather than x/139 will always give an answer that is about .7% too small.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. So, can I add 0.7% to the value I calculated to get the close answer. i.e.  (3900/140) * ( 0.7 /100) +  (3900/140)

Comment: Well at that point you might as well just divide by 139 in the first place. If you do this your dividing by 140/1.007 = 139.02681231380337636544190665343 which is darned close.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if y = c/x (c is a constant) and you make a small change in x, say by h (> 0), then the following happens:

1. The exact relative error is (-h/(c+h))
2. This is approximately equal to (-h/c) [If you take the log and then the differential, that will be evident].